# Zucchini leaves white, but not sure it's PM

Tags: identification, zucchini

I transplanted some zucchini seedlings about 2 weeks ago and one has developed this significant whitening on the leaves. I'm not sure it's powdery mildew. I've had that before, but this looks a bit different. I've applied a baking soda solution and neem oil solution a few days apart but new leaves continue to show the same pattern. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Can you rub the white stuff off, or is the leaf just white?

Comment: Nope just white. Doesn't rub off. Another zucchini planted in a different location is now showing a similar pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a problem at all to me, this is just the variety of zucchini that you have planted!

Powdery Mildew often doesn't create that natural pattern that you see right now on the leaf and it feels different when you touch it.